# PDF Form Fill and Datepicker - REACT

Tags: reactjs, forms, date, pdf, datepicker

I need to build a webapp (REACT) to view/fill PDF forms. The trouble i am having is with date fields. I want to display a date picker when a field in pdf form is of type Date.

I tried pdf.js but was unable to display a date picker.